# How to create a active neural network after using the SPSS module for neural network?

Tags: xml, neural-network, modeling, spss

I created a neural network in SPSS and SPSS gave me a xml file that stores all synaptic weights information. So my question is, is there a easy way to create an active neural network (can predict the future cases)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the NN, on the export tab in the dialog box, specify a file name (with extension xml) as you have done.

When you want to score a dataset, use Utilities > Scoring Wizard and select the xml file you saved.

These actions have equivalent syntax as well as the dialog interfaces.

HTH,
Jon Peck

Comment: what is the propose of scoring dataset? I want to optimum run of ANN in SPSS is scoring belongs to optimization ?